# Why am I getting a json parse error during an ajax call after updating to Codeigniter 3.x?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am updating my Codeigniter framework from **2.2.6 to 3.0.6.** It has broken the existing code that worked before.  Specifically, I am getting the error `"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data" inside the browser console.` I have tried to look and see if this is a known issue when updating, but I have not seen anyone else experiencing this.

Here is the javascript that I am using:

```
    $('#addServiceItem').on('change', function() {
        var serviceID = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/get_service_details/' + serviceID,
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                addServiceItem(data.service);
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
```

Also, here is the function that is being called in the ajax url:

```
public function get_service_details($serviceID = 0)
    {
        if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }

        if ($serviceID == 0) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'service' => null,
                'message' => 'We could not find the service.'
            ));
        }

        $service = $this->services_model->get_service_details($serviceID);

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'service' => $service,
            'message' => ''
        ));
    }
```

As stated above, this code worked in the previous version of Codeigniter. As far as I can tell there is an issue with the Ajax call returning a value. In the javascript variable data stays undefined.  I assume that there is a syntax standard that has changed.

Comment: Check the response in the network tab of your browser's developer tools. See what it contains. It looks like could possibly echo 2 different jsons, since you don't have any sort of die/return if `$serviceID = 0`

Comment: another side note, why are you updating to 3.0.6, when the latest 3.x version is 3.1.11?

Comment: @aynber Thank you so much! looking there allowed me to see that an undefined variable error was getting passed along with the json data, causing it to be misinterpreted.  It looks like the new framework is more strict in regard to undefined variables.

Comment: @Vickel I am picking up development on an existing project.  When I started the project was using version 2.1.4 and I have been stepping through the major updates instead of trying to go straight to the newest.  As soon as my code is stable again I will update to 3.1.11.

Comment: @DMccollum the framework itself is neither more nor less strict regarding undefined variables as versions progress. However, changing PHP versions may result in warnings or notices you weren't getting before. Also, you may have different error reporting levels (maybe your new installation is still set with `development` as its environment and as such would have error reporting enabled for pretty much anything.

Comment: not sure how it was in CI 2.x, but the config specs you'd be looking for are in the core `index.php` file. Look for the sections called `Application environment` and `Error reporting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `$serviceID == 0`, then you get error `Headers already sent` because inside IF you output content and do not terminate code, and outside of IF you again try to set header.

Change your code to this one:

```
public function get_service_details($serviceID = 0)
{
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit('No direct script access allowed');
    }

    if ($serviceID == 0) {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'service' => null,
            'message' => 'We could not find the service.'
        ));

        // Terminate function execution
        return;
    }

    $service = $this->services_model->get_service_details($serviceID);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'service' => $service,
        'message' => ''
    ));
}
```